# python relative import error when referencing file

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, python-module

Now I got relative imports to work by [following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15458607/3834059). But I am getting some errors where the files are referenced with the wrong relative paths.

My folder structure is something like this

```
spamfilter_app
├── Makefile
└── spamfilter
    ├── classifier
    │   ├── classifierNB.py
    │   ├── exceptions.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── train.py
    ├── data
    │   ├── corpus1
    │   ├── corpus2
    │   └── corpus3
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── logfiles
    │   └── logfile.txt
    └──run
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test.py
```

It's absolute path is `/home/tasdik/Desktop/spamfilter_app`

---

My files look something like this

**test.py**

```
from ..classifier.train import Trainer

CUR_DIR = os.path.abspath('.')
PARENT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(CUR_DIR, os.path.pardir))
LOGGING_FILE = os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'logfiles', 'logfile.txt')
CORPUS_DIR = os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'data')

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOGGING_FILE,
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    filemode = 'w',
    format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
```

---

**train.py**

```
from .classifierNB import NaiveBayesClassifier

CUR_DIR = os.path.abspath('.')
PARENT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(CUR_DIR, os.path.pardir))
LOGGING_FILE = os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'logfiles', 'logfile.txt')

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOGGING_FILE,
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    filemode = 'w',
    format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
```

---

**classifierNB.py**

```
CUR_DIR = os.path.abspath('.')
PARENT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(CUR_DIR, os.path.pardir))
LOGGING_FILE = os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'logfiles', 'logfile.txt')

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOGGING_FILE,
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filemode='w',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
```

**Error that I get**

When I do `$ python -m spamfilter.run.test` from the `spamfilter` parent directory, I get this error. Here is the traceback.

```
$ python -m spamfilter.run.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/tasdik/Desktop/spamfilter_app/spamfilter/run/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..classifier.train import Trainer
  File "spamfilter/classifier/train.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .classifierNB import NaiveBayesClassifier
  File "spamfilter/classifier/classifierNB.py", line 43, in <module>
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1540, in basicConfig
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 911, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 936, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tasdik/Desktop/logfiles/logfile.txt'
```

The `logfile.txt` has been given a wrong absolute path. I tried hard coding the path for `logile.txt`, but I faced the same problem when corpus directories were to be accessed

Could anybody explain where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

As suggested, I added the project path to `sys` path by adding

```
sys.path.append("/home/tasdik/Desktop/spamfilter_bad")
```

in each of the mentioned files. And did the imports like

```
from spamfilter.classifier.classifierNB.py import NaiveBayesClassifier
```

I think the imports happen just fine, but the file `logfile error still persists`.

Here is an updated error traceback

```
$ python -m spamfilter.run.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/tasdik/Desktop/spamfilter_app/spamfilter/run/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    from spamfilter.classifier.train import Trainer
  File "spamfilter/classifier/train.py", line 30, in <module>
    from spamfilter.classifier.classifierNB.py import NaiveBayesClassifier
  File "spamfilter/classifier/classifierNB.py", line 46, in <module>
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1540, in basicConfig
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 911, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 936, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tasdik/Desktop/logfiles/logfile.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
replace `os.path.abspath('.')` with `os.path.abspath(__file__)`

`os.path.abspath('.')` gives you different results when you execute your script in different folders. `.` is the current path, it is based on which path invokes the script

**Original Post**

You need to add your project into sys path, and make sure you have `__init__.py` under folder `spamfilter`

`test.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/spamfilter_app")
from spamfilter.classifier.train import Trainer
```

Comment: can you import `Trainer` now with appending the project path to `sys.path`?

Comment: I think imports work fine now, but the lofile.txt error persists. I have updated the error changelog in the question.

Comment: `os.path.abspath('.')`  is based on which folder are you executing ` python -m spamfilter.run.test`. It gives you different results when you are in different paths